# Crash App in Debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-studio-3.0

I've recently had some problems with debugging in Android Studio.

When I run the app in debug mode, the project calculates some value and after that app will be crash

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to changing Instant Run setting it will helps to solve this
go to

```
file > Settings > Build,execution and Deployment > Instant Run
```

Check this box if already unchecked this else uncheck if it's already checked.